# How do you import pygame libraries into Eclipse's pydev?

Tags: python, pygame, pydev, libraries

I have Eclipse working and am working uder the Pydev plugin, and I need some help with pygame. I'm on a mac and have managed to get pygame working for python 3.3 using homebrew, and pydev's causing me some trouble. The libraries don't seem to be recognized. I can use pygame as needed, doing things like

```
import pygame
```

and

```
pygame.init()
```

without problem, but Eclipse doesn't recognize the modules and says things like

```
unresolved import: pygame
```

Again, I think the issue here is Eclipse not having access to the pygame libraries. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows > Preferences > pydev

look for the python interpreter line

on the libraries tab, click new folder and add the pygame folder path, apply and you're done

**NOTE** : make sure to use python 3.x as the project interpreter

Comment: well maybe pygame is not compiled with python3, did you try other versions (based on where pygame is installed, of course)?

Comment: also, just noticed: from within eclipse you can import pygame and run the init() function correctly but you get an import error on pygame? there's something wrong here.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to be more clear. It is for python3. If I type in the terminal "python3" and then "import pygame" it works absolutely fine. And Eclipse isnt actually raising an import error when I run it. The notifications that appear on the side of the file (not the console) are saying things like "variable QUIT is not defined" and "unresolved module: pygame." Also, pydev doesnt list any of the attributes and functions/methods of pygame. I can run any pygame code, like the snippets found at http://inventwithpython.com/pygame/chapter2.html but again, Eclipse isnt configured right with pygame.

Comment: i use pygame too. there's version for python 2.7 aswell. anyway, based on your recent comment, it seems that the problem is another here (init() should not be working if pygame wasn't imported, as you state...) can you please provide more code please? eg: the file where you're getting this error...

Comment: Here's an image album with a few screenies, hopefully this will clear the confusion up http://imgur.com/a/AhH5m#2

Comment: Hum, can you try to import sys before pygame and then print *sys.path* ? may be a problem of the PYTHONPATH variable then (pygame's folder should be visible in that too...) if not, export pygame's folder to PYTHONPATH... it's the last thing i can actually think of to help you

Comment: Here's my path... http://pastebin.com/wijtjH1b Do you know a website which tells you how to modify the PYTHONPATH?

Comment: there should be a pydev-pythonpath under your project - properties

Comment: could you paste the contents of your pythonpath pertaining to pygame? I'll try and see if there's some equivalent on my system

Comment: i have pygame inside the default packages folder, my pyhonpath variable has nothing related to pygame inside. you have a different folder, you just need to add that to pyhonpath

Comment: Hm. Thanks. I think pygame's already in the PYTHONPATH (the pastebin link does mention pygame a few times), but 'll try again. Upvotes for you patience.

Answer (score 1):

I wasted forever trying to get this to work as well. I eventually found these steps (you don't need them all, just part of my struggles are shared here).

in Python Shell:

```
import sys
print (sys.path)
```

I noticed that no PYGAME appeared in path. Eventually I GAVE UP on the .exe binaries and was told to use .WHL files and Python PIP to install. But was told NOT VALID wheel file.

What EVENTUALLY WORKED was (in windows, but similar should work in other OS's) to run Command Prompt as Administrator (just to be sure). Maybe the solution will also work in other OS's (you'd have to try).

From `C:\>` I Changed Dir to my `Python.exe` (or the python program itself).

From my python directory in command prompt I typed the following (Like I would in a linux `apt-get install` command):

```
python.exe -m pip install pygame
```

Shortly after, ther ewere hash marks `#####` indicating a download was taking place (linux type progress bar in shell).

In ECLIPSE without ever changing the Libraries folder to include PyGame folders I was able to run a sample Python PYGAME script sample (I got a white screen but haven't gone further yet). I was just happy to not have to see the trace back error message.

Just thought this would help someone.

Answer (score 0):

python.exe -m pip install pygame   [Worked perfectly]