# setting up eclipse for pygame correctly: "unresolved import"

Tags: python, eclipse, pygame, pydev

Eclipse shows me an error for

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import pygame
```

But when I run the project, pygame obviously works. I can't use the advantages of eclipse IDE like suggestions or auto completion when the editor doesn't 'see' pygame. I wonder why there is no problem in running.
Another thing is that it raises an error when I delete the first line with the coding UTF-8.

I have Ubuntu and my project is set up with python2.7. Interpreter is set correct in preferences. In the libraries /dist-packages/pygame is listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with runnning because python knows where pygame is. Eclipse is not python it may not know where pygame is. I don't use Eclipse but maybe you have to add path to pygame in configuration.

`# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-` is required by python when you use something more than ASCII for example your native chars - even in comments.

**EDIT:**

It seems the same problem: [How do you import pygame libraries into Eclipse's pydev?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126067/how-do-you-import-pygame-libraries-into-eclipses-pydev)

Search *"eclipse pygame"* on `stackoverflow.com` to get more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I saw the other question but it has no solution for me. As I tried to described, I have already added the pygame folder to the libraries.
And I can't use python 3.x as project interpreter, because pygame is not installed for python 3.x. Also I actually don't want to use it. Do I have to?